# three.js Render Scene Only When Ready

Tags: three.js

When a three.js scene is loading, objects and textures appear randomly during the loading of the scene. Is there a graceful way to render a scene only after the entire scene is loaded and ready?

Does three.js fire off an event when this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onLoad function in loading manager https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager.onLoad

Comment: I tried using this, but it would run the scene right  after textures where loaded, and before the scene was ready. Maybe I'm using it wrong, an example would be great.

Comment: Add loading manager to the object loader not texture loader then